# Scala/Spark Change Datetime into EpochTime format

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to change the format of a column datetime into EpochTime but all I could find about this subject is Java.Time.Instant or getEpochSecond and all the functions and everything related to java, but i'm working with scala and I need to change datetime format into EpochTime.

Sample of my datetime column:

```
2013-12-31T05:14:22
2013-12-31T16:49:31
2013-12-30T18:29:20
2013-12-30T21:02:29
```

The format of the datetime I used:

**"yyyy-MMM-dd-HH:mm:ss"**

Code that I tried but gave an error of can't resolve symbol getEpochSecond :

```
 val EpochTime: Long=dataDB.select("Date").getEpochSecond
```

Comment: So basically you want to convert your timestamp column in a dataframe to epoch timestamp (till granularity in seconds). Also, do you know the timezone the timestamp is in? I think without the offset to GMT it would be difficult to convert to exact epoch seconds unless your timestamps are in GMT itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your timstamps are in GMT, the below code should work

```
val inputDF = Seq("2013-12-31T05:14:22","2013-12-31T16:49:31", "2013-12-30T18:29:20", "2013-12-30T21:02:29")
    .toDF("timestamp")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val newDF = inputDF.withColumn("epoch", unix_timestamp(col("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")) // change this timestamp format to offset date

newDF.show(false)
```

If you have timestamps in a particular timezone us e the code below

```
val inputDF = Seq("2013-12-31T05:14:22","2013-12-31T16:49:31", "2013-12-30T18:29:20", "2013-12-30T21:02:29")
    .toDF("timestamp")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df2 = inputDF
.withColumn("timezone", lit("Australia/Sydney")) // Replace "Australia/Sydney by your timezone
.withColumn("time_utc",
  expr("to_utc_timestamp(timestamp, timezone)")
)

val outputDF = df2.withColumn("epoch", unix_timestamp(col("time_utc"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))

outputDF.show(false)
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked out perfectly, I checked the time zone that suppose to come with the data im working on it says +0000 and when I read about it, it's basically UCT, question is how do I include the time zone in the Epoch transition process

Comment: updated answer with the requisite code